# Apache Velocity.init() is throwing an exception

Tags: velocity

I am using Apache Velocity to create html pages but I am getting an exception while initializing.

```
Properties p = new Properties();
String path = EmpowERPlugin.getPluginDir()+IEIFileConstants.VELOCITY_PATH;
p.setProperty("resource.loader","file");            
p.setProperty("file.resource.loader.path", path);
//p.setProperty ("runtime.log.logsystem.class","org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.NullLogSystem");
p.setProperty("class.resource.loader.class", "org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.FileResourceLoader"); 
try{
Velocity.init(p);
}catch(VelocityException e){
e.printStackTrace();
}catch(Exception e1){
e1.printStackTrace()
}finally{
//some code
}
```

while executing Velocity.init() the control directly goes to the finally block instead of catch, so I am not able to guess what type of exception it is

Comment: Welcome to SO. 
Please look at [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please show us some code

Comment: A `finally` block will be executed in *any* case. Sounds as if there actually is no exception at all!

Comment: What would be the output of `try { Velocity.init(p); System.out.println("ok"); } catch(Exception e) { System.out.println("Exception: " + e); }` ?

Comment: I tried the above code, but it is not executing System.out.println("ok"); and it is going into finally

Answer (score 0):

[Exception](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html) class isn't catching all possible exceptions although its tricky name:

> The class Exception and any subclasses that are not also subclasses of RuntimeException are checked exceptions.

I suggest in your case to catch the superclass [Throwable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html):

> The Throwable class is the superclass of all errors and exceptions in the Java language.